# How to get Dell's recovery image without having Windows already installed?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, dell-inspiron

I have an Inspiron 7559-1264. I've tried to install several OSes of my choice to no avail. I want now to resort to the recovery image provided by Dell.

The trouble is when I enter my service tag it prompts me to comply with its license aggreement and then just gives me a small `.exe` file to run on the laptop I want to recover. But I have no OS on that laptop.. since I wiped all the partitions and can't install an OS on that laptop due to its incompatibility with Win 10, Arch, Ubuntu etc..

Dell community forums don't allow me to ask them about this due to premoderation. social.microsoft has no clue either. I don't know what to try else..

UPD: Hey guys, I've done the job using a backup and restore software to make a backup of my Win 10 VM and write it to my boot SSD using bootable USB flash

Comment: if you wiped all the partitions, then your Dell recovery image, was permanently deleted.  I strongly suggest all you do, is download the [Windows 10 installation media ,iso](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) directly from Microsoft, and just install it.  You have not asked a question I feel I can answer, since what you want, is not possible.  You can't use a non-existent Dell recovery image.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried to install Win 10 Pro from Microsoft the day or two before. It hangs during installation "Getting files ready for installation (67%)"

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can always use dells recovery image download tool. Not sure if older computers are supported, but I'm just downloading Windows 10 for my dell and looks good so far. maybe give that a try if you, like me, came to this forum thread in 2018 ;)

https://www.dell.com/support/home/ch/de/chbsdt1/drivers/osiso/recoverytool/

(link's for switzerland but you can just switch to another language on the bottom right of the page)

Answer (score 0):

No way to recover the original image, Dell has never provided this, you can however order the OS backup (reinstall) discs, which will include a drivers disc. See link below

https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/media

You can also download any software that was preinstalled when new, you only get to do this one time for certain software titles, so store the download somewhere safe. See link  below

https://smartsource.dell.com/Web/Welcome.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fweb%2fmain.aspx

Comment: It should be made clear that you don't "need" the media from Dell you can install Windows then install the drivers yourself.  Everything you need can be downloaded by you, from Dell, and installed by you.

Comment: @Ramhound Could you give me a link to Windows 10 Pro that works on that laptop? The one hosted at Microsoft's doesn't

Comment: @rostamn739 - There is no other version of Windows 10, what you would receive from Dell, would be identical to that just an updated .wim.  But if your getting stuck at the installation, it still will get stuck, the Dell media won't solve anything

Comment: Do however take note of x86 and x64 CPU if it is not working

Comment: @RACING121 I have x64 and I tried only x64 shall I install x86?

Comment: @rostamn739 Yh have a try

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 10 installation hangs, try running diskpart's "clean" command.  You have to remove the HD from your computer and attach it to a working Windows computer.  Then,
C:> diskpart
C:> list disk
C:> select disk n (where n is the disk number found in the previous command>
C:> clean
C:> exit